# Getting back rows affected (Int) in Slick 3.0

Tags: scala, slick

In previous versions of Slick, there was insert function defined on a TableQuery that returned an insertion result. I'm migrating to the new API and doing something like:

```
DBIO.seq(someTable += someValue)
```

but this has type

```
dbio.DBIOAction[Unit, NoStream, Write]
```

How can I get back the rows affected?

**edit**

The problem here seems to be that the types aren't lining up the way I would expect them to. Here's what Scala sees the types as:

```
val q: PostgresDriver.DriverAction[PostgresDriver.InsertActionExtensionMethods[(String, String)]#SingleInsertResult, NoStream, Write] = Admins.tableQuery += ((username, grantor))
val seq: dbio.DBIOAction[Unit, NoStream, Write] = DBIO.seq(q)
db.run(seq)
```

This doesn't make sense to me. If `q` has type `DriverAction[PostgresDriver.InsertActionExtensionMethods[(String, String)]#SingleInsertResult...` where SingleInsertResult is a type alias to `Int` then shouldn't my `DBIO.seq` return a `DBIOAction[Int, NoStream, Write]`?

Comment: I didn't follow the details of what stefan did with .seq etc, but this could be just a missing feature, where composing actions doesn't compose the affected rows. Maybe open a ticket at github slick/slick.

Comment: IIRC, `DBIO.seq` is used to group together many different queries (even of different types) but, since it can't return a single value for all queries, it always returns `Future[Unit]` so you can't recover query results, affected rows, etc. See [the docs for DBIO.seq](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/api/index.html#slick.dbio.DBIO$) , *A simpler version of sequence that takes a number of DBIOActions with any return type as varargs and returns a DBIOAction that performs the individual actions in sequence (using andThen), returning () in the end.*

Answer (score 1):

Look at [these examples](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#inserting)

It's not very different from slick 2.x, but now everything returns Futures.

Maybe something along the lines of (off the top of my head, I can't test it myself now)

```
val users = TableQuer[Users]
// this is the query
val q = (users += User(None, "Stefan", "Zeiger"))
// now you run it
db.run(q).map{ affectedRows =>
  case 1 => println("success")
  case _ => println("oops")
}
```